# "Variable may be uninitialized when used here" Xcode compiler warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings

So I wrote this little [program](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) that gives this warning despite the fact that I have the variable initialized, not a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813660/warning-uninitialized-variable-but-i-have-initialized-c-compiler-bug).

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        int num1, num2, product, largestProduct = 0;

        while (num2 < 1000) {

            while (num1 < 1000) {

                product = num1 * num2;

                if (isPalindrome(product)) {

                    largestProduct = product>largestProduct?product:largestProduct;
                }

                num1++;
            }

            num1 = 0; //If I delete that line the warning disappears.
            num2++;
        }

       NSLog(@"%i", largestProduct);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The weird thing is if I delete that commented line the warning disappears, and if I initialize `num1` individually it also disappears. Am I doing something wrong or is that a bug in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
int num1, num2, product, largestProduct = 0;
```

only initializes `largestProduct` to `0`. None of the other variables on that line are explicitly initialized.

It's arguably poor practice to declare multiple variables on one line.

I would suggest:

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int product = 0;
int largestProduct = 0;
```

This is easier to read and debug.

But if you really want one line, do:

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, product = 0, largestProduct = 0;
```

Comment: Is there any popular languages that allow one-line-initialization or is that a general rule? Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: What I describe is true for all C-based languages such as C, C++, and Objective-C. I can't speak to any other language.

Comment: One other comment. Variables should be declared as late as possible to limit their scope. `product` should be declared only where it is used. There is no reason to declare it so far in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @rmaddy's answer, you could also move the line `num1 = 0` above the second while loop. That way, when you actually use the variable `num`, it would have an explicit initialisation value.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        int num1, num2, product, largestProduct = 0;

        while (num2 < 1000) {

            num1 = 0; //Value initialised here.

            while (num1 < 1000) {

                product = num1 * num2;

                if (isPalindrome(product)) {

                    largestProduct = product>largestProduct?product:largestProduct;
                }

                num1++;
            }

            num2++;
        }

       NSLog(@"%i", largestProduct);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works for `num1` but it still leaves `num2` and `product` uninitialized.